# Processing issue : Rendering Graphics on canvas with Vectors

Tags: java, animation, javafx, vector, processing

a bit of a specific question here. I have recently started to read Daniel Shiffman's book "Nature of Code" and started to exercise with Java and Processing. Getting at the last exercise from the Vector's chapter (Chapter 1) , I can't figure out how to make the circle I am drawing move to the cursor...
this is the Mover class ;

```
public class Mover {
PVector location;
PVector acceleration;
PVector velocity;
double radius;
float topSpeed;

public Mover() {
    location = new PVector(200, 200);
    velocity = new PVector(0,0);
    topSpeed = 4;
}

public void update(){
    float mx = (float) MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX();
    float my = (float) MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY();
    PVector mouse = new PVector(mx,my);
    PVector dir = PVector.sub(mouse, location);
    dir.normalize();

     acceleration = dir;
     velocity.add(acceleration);
     velocity.limit(topSpeed);
     location.add(velocity);
}

public void display(GraphicsContext g ){
    g.clearRect(0,0,1000,800);
    g.setFill(Color.RED);
    g.fillOval(location.x,location.y, radius, radius);
}
```

Main class with the FXMLLoader :

```
public class Main extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Noc.fxml"));
    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
    Scene tryout = new Scene(root, 1000, 800, true);
    primaryStage.setScene(tryout);

    primaryStage.setResizable(false);
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

and this is the main FXML class:

```
public class Noc {
        @FXML
    private Canvas can ;
    GraphicsContext g;
    Mover m = new Mover();
@FXML
private void initialize(){
    g = can.getGraphicsContext2D();
    can = new Canvas(1000, 800);
    move();

}
private void move(){
    AnimationTimer at = new AnimationTimer() {
        @Override
        public void handle(long l) {
            m.radius = 30;
            m.update();
            m.checkBounds(); //function to check the edges of the canvas
            m.display(g);
        }
    };
    at.start();

}
```

}

All the other examples I have tried worked perfectly fine, but with this one I seem to have problems. The circle always stop 150-200 pixels away from the mouse. I would appreciate any help/advice

Comment: [mcve] please ..

Comment: @kleopatra I am not sure I can simplify it more than this , or you mean to comment the blocks of code?

Comment: please read the referenced help page and act accordingly (or send me your magic IDE that can compile and run those snippets as-are :))

Comment: Does `MouseInfo.getPointerInfo()` return the screen position of the cursor instead of its position within the stage? If so that could be the problem.